# React app produces 404 error without any reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx

I am new in React, and want to start a simple UI server.

**The issue** in that my server finished answer to me from any reason. I just changed `Login.js` and rolled back after. You can skip all information that I provided bottom and move to the end of question - "please give me a tip what do I can to do for understanding the issue and how to repair server to the working mode?"

---

I created my very first solution where I have created App.js and Login.js:

#### File *App.js*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Login';
import Home from './Home';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    loggedIn: false,
    loading: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount App.js");
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
    if (token) {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
    }
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    const { loggedIn } = this.state;
    console.log('loggedIn ' + loggedIn);
    return (
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/home">
                {loggedIn ? <Home /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/login">
                {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Login />}
              </Route>
              <Redirect to="/home" />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### File *Login.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    loggedIn: false,
  };

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'email': this.state.username,
          'password': this.state.password
        }

      });

      // Handle the login response, assuming it returns a JWT token on success
      if (response.ok) {
        const token = response.headers.get('Authorization');
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token); // Store the JWT token in local storage
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true }); // Update the logged in state
      } else {
        // Handle login error
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle login error
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'); // Retrieve the JWT token from local storage
    if (token) {
      this.setState({ loggedIn: true }); // User is already logged in
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loggedIn) {
      // Redirect the user to the App component or the appropriate endpoint
//      return <Redirect to="/home" />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Login Page</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            placeholder="Username"
            value={this.state.username}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
        <Link to="/signup">SignUp</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

And file *gitlab-ci.yml*:

```yaml
image: node

cache:
  paths:
    - frontend/node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq
  - apt-get install -qq git
  - "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install -qq openssh-client )"
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 --decode | tr -d "\r")
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd frontend
    - ls
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - ls
    - scp -r build/* root@167.172.164.152:/var/www/html
```

---

This solution was working. I have received a login page, fields and was making requests to the my API server. Since I had some issues with requesting API server I did ONLY ONE single changing:

I made small update in `Login.js` (`const response = await fetch('/login'` -> `'/api/login`) *and it all*. After that I started receiving 404 error from any reason. I do rolled back the changes but I still can't get access to the my page. (/login or /home, or any other).
I understand that this issue is confusing and not normal and nobody can give the answer - all what I ask: could anyone direct me where I can search solution, how to debug this, where do I can find logs and etc... What would you do in my situation?

---

Additional info:

DevTools console output:

```
login:1     GET http://167.172.164.---/login 404 (Not Found)
login:4 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
login:4 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
login:4 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
login:4 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
login:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Full error:

```html
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

The difference in */var/log/ginx/access.log*:

Success:

```
94.230.196.208 - - [04/Aug/2023:08:58:50 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.c2cde8cb.js HTTP/1.1" 200 182348 "http://167.172.164.---/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
94.230.196.208 - - [04/Aug/2023:08:58:50 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.ff79ec8e.css HTTP/1.1" 200 166750 "http://167.172.164.---/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
94.230.196.208 - - [04/Aug/2023:08:58:51 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3870 "http://167.172.164.---/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
94.230.196.208 - - [04/Aug/2023:08:58:57 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.ff79ec8e.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://167.172.164.---/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
94.230.196.208 - - [04/Aug/2023:08:58:57 +0000] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200 492 "http://167.172.164.---/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

404:

```
46.252.215.-- - - [04/Aug/2023:20:26:51 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
46.252.215.-- - - [04/Aug/2023:20:26:52 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://167.172.164.---/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
46.252.215.-- - - [04/Aug/2023:20:31:12 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.188"
46.252.215.-- - - [04/Aug/2023:20:31:12 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3870 "http://---/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.188"
```

That is all what I can to do, and I nothing can analyze - you can see the difference in that how to /login page called in the first and second logs. I have no idea why, and what it is the difference means.

Comment: Please, _please_ start using modern HTML5. `<center>` and the `bgcolor` attribute haven't been part of HTML since 1997, when HTML3.2 got replaced by HTML4. Which got replaced by HTML 4.01 in 1999, which in turn got replaced by HTML5 back in 2014. Also MSIE _doesn't exist anymore_, it was officially killed off by MS last year. The only browser MS makes is Edge.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use those attributes - this is answer from the nginx server :)